# delete rows ff package

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

Since a while now I´ve been using ff package in order to work with big data. The R object I´ve worked with has about 130.000.000 rows and 14 columns. Two of those columns, Temperature and Precipitation have missing values “NA” so I need to delete those rows in order to move forward with my work.
I´ve been trying to do it like I would in a normal R object:

```
data<-data[!is.na(data$temp),]
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
Error: vmode(index) == "integer" is not TRUE
```

Does anyone have been able to delete rows in a ffdf object?
I´d appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7):

Indexing based on a logical ff_vector is not possible in ff, you need to supply a vector of ff integers. That is what the error message is trying to tell you. So you can do the subsetting like this

```
require(ffbase)
idx <- !is.na(data$temp)
idx <- ffwhich(idx, idx == TRUE)
data <- data[idx, ]
```

or (using version 6.3 of ffbase)

```
require(ffbase)
data <- subset(data, !is.na(temp))
```

Comment: I have just seen your answer, thank you so much for your help. I´ll check it out and see how it goes.